# SQL Server 2016 - sp_execute_external_script

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute a new stored proc in 2016 named sp_execute_external_script. I first need to enable external scripts as follows:

```
sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;
```

After doing this, I see this message:

```
Configuration option 'external scripts enabled' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

I then execute `RECONFIGURE` and see a message saying, `"Command(s) completed successfully"`.

I then attempt to execute the following, to see if R is working correctly:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script @language =N'R',
@script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',
@input_data_1 =N'select 1 as hello'
with result sets (([hello] int not null));
go
```

When I do so, I see the following error:

```
Msg 39023, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 3]
'sp_execute_external_script' is disabled on this instance of SQL Server. Use sp_configure 'external scripts enabled' to enable it.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: If you run `sp_configure 'external scripts enabled';` what is the run_value returned? You may need to restart SQL Server first.

Comment: The need to restart SQL Server after changing this parameter is documented behavior: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590884.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After turning on external scripts, you'll need to restart SQL Server so that when you run

```
sp_configure 'external scripts enabled';
```

it returns a run_value of 1:

```
name                                minimum     maximum     config_value run_value
----------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ -----------
external scripts enabled            0           1           1            1
```

Documentation: [External Scripts Enabled server configuration option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/external-scripts-enabled-server-configuration-option)

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure your SQL Server Launchpad Service is started. If the service is stopped, sp_configure 'external scripts enabled' will not have any effect running external scripts.

Kingshuk.